# Using MD5 Hash to compare database records

Tags: java, sql, md5

A common issue in health related records (and I am sure other types of database records) is that a single patient may appear in the master index under multiple individual records.  This may result in the patient having multiple ID's.  It occurred to me that one way of managing this would be to build an MD5 hash of fixed information and then compare hashes.  For example, we could assume that first name, last name, birth date and address would be consistent.  They could be concatenated together in a single String, have spaces removed and all made lower case.  The String could then be parsed through an MD5 algorithm.  Whilst this is not fail-safe (addresses could change), it may help.  I would really like some feedback on this or maybe a suggestion of an alternate methodology?

Comment: Why don't you just index the existing fields?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this method if you remove the **Address** thing from the input string. Addresses can change and sometimes people mis-spell addresses in laziness. I suggest adding another element except address and don't just keep first name, last name and DOB because though the probability is not high there may be collisions. A simple implementation:

```
   String first_name = "Abdul";
   String last_name = "Ansari";
   String DOB = "29/09/1994";
   String fourth_element = ""; //Add something
   String data = first_name + last_name + DOB + fourth_element;
   data = data.replaceAll(" ","");
   data = data.toLowerCase();
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   md.update(data.getBytes());
   byte[] digest = md.digest();
   // Then convert the bytes to hex and add them in database
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a point in using MD5. The string you create could be used instead to compare equality.

Alternatively, you could have several levels of matching. For example, if matched firstname, lastname, birthday, and address then a perfect match which then get translated to be the same person. On the other hand, firstname, lastname, birthday, but not address, then will be reviewed by a human to decide if it is a match or not...

Comment: I see your point, however I guess the complexity with health records is the potential need for the data to be "de-identified".  The hash would capture the duplicates without revealing the names.  I admit this was not my original intention, just thinking allowed.